# What is the p-adic Plancherel measure?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, notation, p-adic-analysis

What I know as the Plancherel measure for a group is a measure on the spectrum of $G$, aka the set of irreducible representations - at least for finite groups, this makes perfect sense.

Now, this [paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa78/aa7848.pdf) by Conrey, Duke and Farmer defines a measure $\mu_p(\theta) = \frac{2}{\pi}(1+\frac1p)\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{(1-\frac1p)^2 + \frac4p\sin^2(\theta)}d\theta$ and mentions that this is known as a p-adic Plancherel measure.

What does this mean? What is the group for which this is the Plancherel measure and how is it's spectrum identified with $S^1$? I suspect that the group is $PGL_2(\mathbb Q_p)$ but I don't know what it's spectrum looks like.

Comment: After looking at the paper (they thank Peter Sarnak for the remark that it is the "p-adic Plancherel measure"), it seems that the Plancherel measure is not of  the group $PGL(2,{\mathbb Q}_p)$ but that of the quotient space $PGL(2,{\mathbb Q}_p)/PGL(2,{\mathbb Z}_p)$. The irreducibles (unramified principal series which are unitary) occurring here are indeed parametrised  by $S^1$, namely characters on the split torus $T({\mathbb Q}_p)$ modulo $T({\mathbb Z}_p)$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Do you have a reference where I can learn more about this?

Comment: any book which has representations of GL(2,{\mathbb Q}_p)$ would consider unramified representations (and Satake parameters). Maybe Bump's book?